# Compare two query results and check if value exist in both of them

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table ([DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8fc3c52cf0f4e8ee1433fd0023080443))**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    sales_date DATE,
    insert_time DATE
);

INSERT INTO sales
(product, sales_date, insert_time
)
VALUES 
("Product A", "2020-04-15", "2020-03-05"),
("Product B", "2020-05-20", "2020-03-05"),
("Product C", "2020-02-11", "2020-03-05"),

("Product A", "2020-04-15", "2020-03-06"),
("Product B", "2020-05-20", "2020-03-06"),
("Product C", "2020-02-11", "2020-03-06"),

("Product A", "2020-04-15", "2020-03-07"),
("Product B", "2020-05-20", "2020-03-07"),
("Product C", "2020-02-11", "2020-03-07");
```

In the table above each day the sales of products are inserted and assigned to the `insert_time`.

---

Now I want to check per `insert_time` if the products in the result of this query:

```
SELECT
product,
sales_date
FROM sales
WHERE insert_time = "2020-03-05";
```

also appear in the results of this query:

```
SELECT
product,
sales_date
FROM sales
WHERE insert_time = "2020-03-05"
AND sales_date BETWEEN insert_time AND DATE_ADD(insert_time, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

---

The final result should look like this:

```
product           sales_date         Check
Product A         2020-04-15         O.K.
Product B         2020-05-20         O.K.
Product C         2020-02-11         Error  (--> Because it only appears in the first query)
```

---

How do I have to merge the two queries in order to achive the expected result?

Comment: Try `INTERSECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CASE` expression with `EXISTS` comes to mind:

```
SELECT s.product, s.sales_date,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM sales s2
                          WHERE s2.product = s.product AND
                                s2.sales_date BETWEEN s2.insert_time AND DATE_ADD(s2.insert_time, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
                         )
             THEN 'OK' ELSE 'ERROR'
        END) as flag
FROM sales s
WHERE s.insert_time = '2020-03-05';
```

Note that `check` is a bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword (used for `check` constraints).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=acf66219302a9e6b216ae7bd6afda5ee

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using a CASE statement:

```
SELECT
product,
sales_date,
    CASE
    WHEN sales_date BETWEEN insert_time AND DATE_ADD(insert_time, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) THEN 'Ok'
    ELSE 'Error' END AS 'Check'
FROM sales
WHERE insert_time = "2020-03-05";
```

You could also use a LEFT JOIN, but this means you have to hit the table twice:

```
SELECT all_records.product, all_records.sales_date, ifnull(filtered_records.Check, 'Error') AS `Check`
FROM
(
SELECT
product,
sales_date,
'Ok' AS 'Check'
FROM sales
WHERE insert_time = "2020-03-05"
) all_records
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
product,
sales_date,
'OK' AS 'Check'
FROM sales
WHERE insert_time = "2020-03-05"
AND sales_date BETWEEN insert_time AND DATE_ADD(insert_time, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
) filtered_records
 ON all_records.product = filtered_records.product
 AND all_records.sales_date = filtered_records.sales_date
```